# Remove news, description and image from collection and communities

Tags: xml, dspace, mirage

How can i remove news, description and image from the main collection and collection view in dspace. What are the files to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Mirage2 UI, the following files would need to be modified.

- https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/collection-view.xsl
- https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/community-view.xsl

For the Mirage UI, the following files would need to be modified

- https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser/collection-view.xsl
- https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser/community-view.xsl

Comment: Thank you for this. I just dont know which part of the two files to change. I have tried changing them and packing the project but no change.

Comment: After making the change, did you run the maven build, run the ant build and restart tomcat?

I recommend that you start a new question detailing what you have tried so far.  Include the code that you have tried to edit.